# What is -p doing in bash regex test?

Tags: regex, bash

I have this test in a bash script and, while I have some vague idea, I want to be sure what exactly is going on.

```
if [[ "$FLAGS" =~ -p' '+-?[0-9]+ ]]
```

I can tell that it is testing some regex on `$FLAGS`, but I am not sure why the `-p` is needed.

In general, I want to know what is the `-p` doing in a bash regex test. (and, ideally, where to look for similar things in manpages.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"-p" in this context is part of the regexp. The regexp is looking for a match to any of the following patterns:

```
-p 123
-p123
-p -123
-p-123
```

The " " and the second "-" are optional.

Comment: Oh, I thought that it's a special flag of the regex test, and I couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: @KarelBílek: Don't forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

BASH will treat **everything after `=~` operator** as regex so BASH will try to match against this regex:

```
-p' '+-?[0-9]+
```